# How to replace/remove comma from a tezt using Selenium+java?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

My Webpage contains text like 'User,'. I need to capture this text without comma. When i am doing assertEquals between the user entered text(User) and text retrieved from the webpage(User,), it failed because of extra comma.Can you help how to replace or remove that comma and getText?

Using the below xpath, i am capturing the text,
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainContents']/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).getText();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you place your text in `t` and you only want to remove the last comma (if present)

```
    t=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainContents']/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).getText();
    if(t.charAt(t.length()-1).equals(","))
        t=t.substring(0,t.length()-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainContents']/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).getText().replace(",", "")
```

Comment: replace will replace all commas in the string. If his text (username, I'm guessing) contains (by any chance) commas, those will also be replaced.

Answer (score -1):

```
string usertext=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainContents']/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).getText();     
string actual = usertext.replace(",");  
Assert.equals(expected, actual );
```